# Whats the fastest way to get a specific WAMP stack running locally?

Tags: wamp

I need PHP 5.2.13, MySQL 5.0.77 and Apache 2.2 running on Windows to replicate a server environment. What's the quickest way to get that up and running? I need it for a legacy ExpressionEngine install (1.6.8) as it will not run on my Mac (don't ask)> Local OS is Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those component versions are seriously out-of-date, but if you really need it, you'll be able to find an older version of one of the WAMP packages.

The big list of WAMPs is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs

The big free ones are XAMPP and WampServer.

The one I use is called WampDeveloper Pro, it's commercial (not-free) but production-ready and has a full UI that manages everything for you, including switching to different versions of Apache, PHP, and MYSQL... But I don't think it has the older MySQL 5.0.